# Validatig date input- timestamp microservice

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, momentjs

i am having problem when trying to validate my date input. i tried this using moment js but seems there's an issue. I am always getting date invalid!

here's my code:

```
app.get("/api/timestamp/:date_string", function (req,res,next){

var date_string = req.params.date_string;

var date = moment(date_string, 'DD-MM-YYYY', true);
if (date.isValid())
{ req.time = new Date(date_string).toUTCString();
req.unix = new Date(date_string).getTime();
}

else if (!date.isValid()){

req.time= "invalid date";
req.unix= "error";
}

else {
req.time = new Date().toUTCString();
req.unix = new Date().getTime();
}


next();

}, function (req,res) {

res.json ({
        unix: req.unix,
        utc: req.time 
         })

})
```

can't figure where the inconvenience is?

Comment: I'd suggest you try to isolate the problem: what is the date input that is failing? can you create a 3-4 line [mcve] that shows the problem?

Comment: i am taking input from: app.get("/api/timestamp/:date_string") and then trying to verify whether it's avalid date or not using: var date = moment(date_string, 'DD-MM-YYYY', true); but date.isValid seems always getting false!!

Answer (score 1):

here's the correct code for those who might need it:

```
app.get("/api/timestamp/:date_string", function (req,res,next){

var date_string = req.params.date_string;

var date = Date.parse(date_string)
if (isNaN(date)==false)
{ req.time = new Date(date_string).toUTCString();
req.unix = new Date(date_string).getTime();
}

else if (isNaN(date)==true){

req.time= "invalid date";
req.unix= "null";
}

else {
req.time = new Date().toUTCString();
req.unix = new Date().getTime();
}


next();

}, function (req,res) {

res.json ({unix: req.unix,
        utc: req.time })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

try by playing with Date.parse

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse